# Remember multi-factor authentication on trusted device with custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have implemented the Email or Phone MFA custom policy and now Added KMSI configuration on top of it.

But as MFA is enabled, even if user ticks Remember me in the first place and comes back after sometime it asks to validate using MFA method.

Is there a way in custom policy to remember MFA authentication for X number of days so user don't need to provide MFA details even after checking KMSI?

**Scenario I am testing :**

Logging in to application and clicking on Remember Me  
Entering MFA Details  
Successfully logged in 
Closing Browser Window

Again opening the browser window , user is presented with MFA screen directly as remember me was ticked (login screen is bypassed)

**Expected Outcome :**
User don't need to provide MFA details again and should already logged In.

Answer (score 0):

Your option is to create a custom policy that takes the factors you want into account. Here are two examples.

[MFA after timeout or IP change](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/mfa-absolute-timeout-and-ip-change-trigger) - A policy which forces the user to do MFA on 3 conditions:

The user has newly signed up.
The user has not done MFA in the last X seconds.
The user is logging in from a different IP than they last logged in from.

[Unknown Devices MFA](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/mfa-unknown-devices) - Demonstrates how to detect unknown devices which might be required to prompt MFA as illustrated in this particular sample or send email to the user signing in from unknown device.

Comment: How can we keep both remember me checkbox value - true/false and IP timeout for MFA in sync? If user haven't checked the kmsi I want the normal flow (ignore IP extension technical profile)  and If checked then only apply it.

Comment: @jas-suri-msft can you please help on this?

Comment: You can resolve whether the user dejected KMSI using a [claims resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#context). Then use that to drive your logic with preconditions.